# SD card shows up as Internal in Disk Utility

Tags: macos

I recently Installed Sierra on my sandisk 32 GB sd card which was not bootable after I formatted it it shows up as Internal how to I fix this issue?

output of diskutil list:

```
$ /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 C8FBDE46-9264-4EF1-8287-2AA808659654
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *31.9 GB    disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SD CARD                 31.6 GB    disk2s2
```

Comment: Please pretty up your barren question with some details like `sudo gpt -r show disk0` and/or `diskutil list` by entering these commands in Terminal.app and adding the output(s) to your question.

Comment: There's nothing harmful in connecting over target disk mode and seeing what you can restore / repair / recover. putting in the details klanomath needs is a great idea - you might simply have a small corruption in a lookup table and need a tiny band aid and not reconstructive surgery or worse.

Comment: It likely depends on how much messing around you've already done on the disk to get into your current state - ref: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286480/macbook-wont-boot-after-creating-two-small-partitions Note that backups are what you need **before** your drive fails, not afterwards.

Comment: Can I get back all of my files in Target disk mode?

Comment: You have the same chance in Target Disk Mode as if you took out the drive & mounted it directly. You will still need to choose some kind of recovery software, Disk Drill etc. Adding the info requested by klanomath will give a better clue.

Comment: I assume the problem relates to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286480/macbook-wont-boot-after-creating-two-small-partitions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot back it up if the partition information is damaged. You first need to repair the damage. Sounds like it is the root/boot disk, which means you don't want to try using it.

Yes you can boot your damaged Mac into Target disk mode by pressing the T key right after powering it on. Then plug it into another Mac. The damaged disk will appear as a drive on the good Mac. Run diskutil to repair your damaged disk.

Comment: I don't have another Mac will an AASP allow to access my files on their Mac?

Comment: Is it ok if I install an OS on the 15GB partition because I  have already installed the OS on the partition and it works fine.

Comment: Yes if you are starting over that is fine. You won't be able to recover the old data any more, but you can start fresh yes.

Comment: So can I atleast recover my photos and my desktop?